# Setting permissions in PHP on server

Tags: php, file, upload, permissions

I am trying to create a really simple webpage in php, letting people upload images to a folder on my server. I made this really simple with some done code, and it worked awesomely on my computer with xampp, but when I upload the page to my server, it gets an error message every time I upload anything. The error is when the script checks if the image was uploaded, where it says

```
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if(!$copied)
   echo "error";
```

This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the permissions. But how can I set this? And what should I set it to? I just need others to be able to upload images to a spesific folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server needs write permissions to be able to write into the directory you're storing the images.

Assuming you're on a Linux server, run the following command on the server (ssh) after changing `/path/to/uploaded/images` to the image upload directory, and see if it solves the problem:

```
chmod 777 /path/to/uploaded/images
```

If that fixes the problem, you can probably relax the permissions to something like:

```
chmod 664 /path/to/uploaded/images
```

These are basic commands for directory permissions, which you can learn more about in [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions) about file permissions on Linux.

Alternatively, you can use [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) to copy the uploaded file to a known location.

Comment: Okay, thanks for quick reply. But, I myself just have permissions in a subfolder on the server. It is a school-server, in which I have to enter username and password to access the folder of my student number. Does it help to change the permissions of just this folder, or do I have change the permissions for the entire school..?

Comment: You can change the permissions of just the folder. You may need to [set the execute permission bit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened) so the webserver can "see" the upload directory. But you really only need to modify the permissions on the one folder.